# regular expression for certain characters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a regular expression that does not seem to work for me so I'm thinking that my syntax is incorrect.  I'm trying to look for any character that is above the numbers on a typical keyboard (e.g. !@#$%^&*()).

Here is the syntax that I'm using in my expression variable.

```
var expSpecialChar = /[!@#$%^&*()]/
```

Here is my statement to test for the characters.  The statement is wrapped in a function that is called when a button is clicked.

```
expSpecialChar.test($("#tbText").val();
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: And? What happens? Does it work? Not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `)` at the end of your second code sample.

The following seems to work fine for me

**HTML**

```
<input id="tbText" />
<button>Test</button>
<div id="result"></result>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var expSpecialChar = /[!@#$%^&*()]/ 
    var result = expSpecialChar.test($("#tbText").val());  
    $("#result").text(result);
  });
});
```

#### See it working on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kDTHm/